# Deploy Laravel to Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I am new to deploy a website.

I have all the code about the website in my laptop, but I don't know how to
move it to the real server the Microsoft Azure.

Could anyone tell me how to deploy Laravel 5+ to Azure or any tutorials about it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 major Azure service we can use to deploy projects on, which are Virtual Machines, Cloud Services and Web Apps. But the simplest way is to deploy on Web Apps server.

Here are the steps to deploy PHP project on Azure Web Apps Server by git:

1, Sign in [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) , Click “NEW” in bottom, select “COMPUTE”=>”WEB APP”=>”QUICK CREATE” and enter server name in URL section, to create a new empty Web application.
[image]

2, Click “WEB APP” button on the left navigation, in this dashboard we can see the web site we created above, click web site name to enter in management page.

[image]

3, In dashboard page, click “set up deployment form source control” in “quick glance” column, select “Local Git repository” to create a git repository. Now in deployments page, we can see the guide to deploy project by git.

4, In your local project root directory, run the following commands to deploy as shown on the page:

[image]

Furthermore, we can simply use FTP tool to upload the project to Azure Server, please see this simple sample:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sams_blog/archive/2014/11/14/azure-websites-deploy-php-website-using-ftp.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary Liu.

Comment: yeah, the server is running well now, even the MySQL database, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample on deploying a Laravel 5+ Application straight from Github.

In fact, if you have an Azure Subscription clicking the button below will configure a Web App, MySQL Database and Redis Cache Server with Laravel.

[image: Deploy to Azure]