# Migrating existing wordpress site to azure show me a blank page after import xml content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, content-management-system

I am moving an existing word press site to azure, I am trying to use Tools => Import, I installed the "Import WordPress" plugin, but after upload the XML it takes some minutes and shows me a blank page, then I notice that no posts, comments, pages, etc. were imported.

Comment: Could you post more information? Maybe a small part of your exported XML-File, to be able to check the structure.

Comment: It's a 1Mb xml generated by the Import WordPress plugin

Answer (score 0):

When you import your .XML file, you have the message with a succefully importing? Or some wrong message?

Normally this kind of situations with WordPress migrations it was about memory limit, you can change it in your wp-settings.php

If you have 32 M change it for 128M and try again.

```
'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M'
```

If you are in a shared-hosted you need to talk with your provider, if not be sure that you have memory to upload big files.

Comment: I select the file, click Upload and Import, then reAssign Authors, I checked the box "Download and import file attachments" and Submit. After that, not error at all, after a while just show me a blank page.

Comment: The XML file is just 1Mb. I increased the memory limit, but still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the all content of my WordPress on local and imported to Azure platform, but I still couldn’t reproduce your issue. May you supply the XML snippets for further discussing?

In order to find the cause of the problem, you need to turn on the **display_errors** setting on to check if there were any PHP error, to configure PHP setting on Azure, you can follow the steps:

1, Add a .user.ini file to your root directory.

2, Add configuration settings to the .user.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file. With your demand, your .user.ini file would contain this text:

`display_errors  = On
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept, If needed.
post_max_size = 20M`

3, Deploy your web app.

4, Restart the web app.

Also, we can use FTP tool or WebMatrix to connect your Azure Web sites server to create and modify the custom configuration file.

Another approach about migrated an existing application to Azure Web Apps is that we can use FTP Tool or Git to upload the whole application folder to the root directory on Azure.

You can see step by step reference on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109245/deploy-laravel-to-azure/32111796#32111796).

The default root directory is `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.